# Conditional removing duplicate records

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm storing some realtime data in SQLite. Now, I want to remove duplicate  records to reduce data and enlarge its timeframe to 20 seconds by SQL commands.

**Sample data:**

```
id     t        col1    col2  
-----------------------------
23  9:19:18     15      16   
24  9:19:20     10      11
25  9:19:20     10      11   
26  9:19:35     10      11   
27  9:19:45     10      11   
28  9:19:53     10      11   
29  9:19:58     14      13
```

**Logic:** In above sample, records 25-28 have same value in col1 and col2 field, so they are duplicate. But because keeping one (for example, record 25) and removing others will cause timeframe (= time difference between subsequent data) to be more than 20s, i don't want to remove all of records 26-28. So, in above sample, row=25 will be kept because, it's not duplicate of its previous row. Row=26 will be kept, because although its duplicate of its previous row, removing this row causes to have timeframe to more than 20s (19:45 - 19:20). Row=27 will be removed, meeting these 2 conditions and row=28 will be kept.

I can load data to C# datatable and apply this logic in code in a loop over records, but it is slow comparing to run SQL in database. I'm not sure this can be implemented in SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: I've added another row before row =25 to show rows with the same time. Fiddle is here: [Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=82a5ae9188511040bdbf92702db5fd79)

Comment: What does `t` represent? Is it `hh:mm` or `mm:ss`?

Comment: It is mm:ss. It's my mistake in removing hour. I edited sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so here's an alternate answer that handles the duplicate record scenario you've described, uses LAG and LEAD and also ends up considerably simpler as it turns out!

```
delete from t1 where id in
(
with cte as (
select id, 
       lag(t, 1) over(partition by col1, col2 order by t) as prev_t,
       lead(t, 1) over(partition by col1, col2 order by t) as next_t
from t1
)
select id
from cte
where strftime('%H:%M:%S',next_t,'-20 seconds') < strftime('%H:%M:%S',prev_t)
)
```

Online demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=66375a71dcc971d75fbf3dab2518f9f1)

Comment: Thanks. This solution also covers unsorted t fields which is a good precaution in my case.

Comment: Great! Good to get your feedback.

Comment: Adding more data, it sounds to me that old problem still exists. Check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9543447771eb875f84498bd932f3b54d  In final result, time difference between 2nd and 3rd row is greater than 20 seconds. I accept that this is my mistake in describing problem in first post. As a programmer, this problem has no solution except using a loop which may be applicable in SQL using CTE recursive. Am i right?

Comment: It definitely helps to have more representative data to illustrate the problem! I'm out of time to review it further today. May get more time tomorrow...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this accomplishes what you are after:

```
delete from t1 where id in
(
select ta.id 
from t1 as ta
join t1 as tb 
   on tb.t = (select max(t) from t1 where t < ta.t 
               and col1 = ta.col1 and col2 = ta.col2)
   and tb.col1 = ta.col1 and tb.col2 = ta.col2
join t1 as tc  
   on tc.t = (select min(t) from t1 where t > ta.t 
               and col1 = ta.col1 and col2 = ta.col2)
   and tc.col1 = ta.col1 and tc.col2 = ta.col2
where strftime('%H:%M:%S',tc.t,'-20 seconds') < strftime('%H:%M:%S',tb.t)
)
```

Online demo is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f6f38794f58d5b24ca59137dae47be6a) where I've gone through a couple of iterations to simplify it to the above. Basically you need to look at **both** the previous row **and** the next row to determine whether you can delete the current row, which happens only when there's a difference of less than 20 seconds between the previous and next row times, as I understand your requirement.

Note: You could probably achieve the same using LAG and LEAD but I'll leave that as an exercise to anyone else who's interested!!

EDIT: In case the time values are not unique, I've included additional conditions to the ta/tb and ta/tc joins to include col1 and col2 and updated the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds working and I'm going to test its performance on real large amount of data. About LAG and LEAD, one guy provided me with this solution which although not completely fits my needs, i insert it here so that may be helpful for others: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=db43dea7f2f9dcb344267b19ed6e1247

Comment: If you have indexes over col1 and col2 (and possibly t as well), the performance should be pretty good.

Comment: One little problem. Look at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=82a5ae9188511040bdbf92702db5fd79 . I've added another row with same time and values (a completely copy of another row with different id). This kind of rows will not be removed by your code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm, to be fair, that scenario is not covered in your original description of the problem. This is essentially a "duplicate record" situation, which is an additional consideration that will require further/amended logic. It also leads me to question "How do these duplicates get in there in the first place"? (Although that doesn't help, if you just being handed a situation you have to deal with). You mention "realtime" data. So are these genuine duplicates or is it just that they are not being recorded with an accurate timestamp (e.g. nearest microsecond)? I'll take a look at the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a million @user9601310. You're completely right. In fact, this table is created by merging 2 table (each one getting realtime data for its own) to cover problems in getting data like bad internet connection, slow server response, ...

Comment: So, have you managed to try out the alternate answer provided? Does it produce the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following:

1. Create a result set in SQL that adds the previous row ordered by id (for this use LAG function (https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-lag/)
2. Calculate a new column using the CASE construct (https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-case/). This column could be a boolean called "keep" that basically is calculated in the following way:

   - if the previous row col1 and col2 values are not the same => true
   - if the previous row col1 and col2 values are the same but the time difference > 20 sec => true
   - in other cases => false
3. Filter on this query to only select the rows to keep (keep = true).

Comment: This way row=28 will also be removed. I want to keep it, because removing this will cause time difference be greater than 20 seconds